# Assign a tensorflow variable to an element in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and when I play with it. I met some problems

```
import numpy as np

t_p2 = tf.Variable(5., dtype=tf.float32)
spar_f = tf.exp(t_p2)

A = np.array(3)
A[0] = spar_f
```

Then an error was raised:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

In general, if I want to assign a tensorflow object to an element in an numpy array. 
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

t_p2 = tf.Variable(5., dtype=tf.float32)
spar_f = tf.exp(t_p2)

A = np.array([3])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(t_p2.initializer)
    A[0] = sess.run(spar_f)

print(A)
```

Note that you did turn A into an array in your original example.

So what are you missing ? The [first part of the getting started tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) where the paradigm gets explained, in tensorflow first you define a graph. Once the graph is constructed you use that graph within a session to run the calculation. What I did in the example above, ran the calculation and stored the result in a numpy array.